# Ruby on Rails - custom validation allowing isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn custom validation. Below is the simple code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, presence: true,length: { in: 6..20 }
  validate :name_cannot_be_tushar

  def name_cannot_be_tushar
    if username == "Tushar"
        errors.add(:username, "can't be Tushar")
    end
  end
end
```

When I am trying to insert data through rails console,

> 2.3.0 :014 > User.create(username:"Tushar",password:"ABC")
>      (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>     SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["username", "Tushar"], ["password", "ABC"], ["created_at", "2016-04-14 09:23:14.077264"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-14 09:23:14.077264"]]
>      (12.9ms)  commit transaction
>    => # 
>   2.3.0 :015 >

It is letting me insert the data. What do I change to make my custom validation method work?

Comment: Which version of Rails you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine. You may need to restart `rails console`, and it will work fine. Rails console session doesn't automatically load recent changes in your model.

Comment: I would just make the validation method `private` and make it return a boolean.

Comment: such a Railsism to have to restart the server after adding a model validation

Comment: @duhaime or you may type `reload!` in the console session